# Interpreting plot.lm()

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, residuals, outliers

I had a question about interpreting the graphs generated by plot(lm) in R.  I was wondering if you guys could tell me how to interpret the scale-location and leverage-residual plots?  Any comments would be appreciated.  Assume basic knowledge of statistics, regression and econometrics.

Comment: have you has a look [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/plot.lm.html)?

Comment: and [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Faraway-PRA.pdf) (from page 72 on), [here](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/classes/s133/Lr0.html).

Answer (score 156):

As stated in [the documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/plot.lm.html), `plot.lm()` can return 6 different plots:

> **[1]** a plot of residuals against fitted values, **[2]** a Scale-Location plot of sqrt(| residuals |) against fitted values, **[3]** a Normal Q-Q plot, **[4]** a plot
>   of Cook's distances versus row labels, **[5]** a plot of residuals against
>   leverages, and **[6]** a plot of Cook's distances against
>   leverage/(1-leverage). By default, the first three and 5 are provided.  (*my numbering*)

Plots **[1]**, **[2]**, **[3]** & **[5]** are returned by default.  Interpreting **[1]** is discussed on CV here: [Interpreting residuals vs. fitted plot for verifying the assumptions of a linear model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/76226/).  I explained the assumption of homoscedasticity and the plots that can help you assess it (including scale-location plots **[2]**) on CV here: [What does having constant variance in a linear regression model mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/52107/7290)  I have discussed qq-plots **[3]** on CV here: [QQ plot does not match histogram](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/52221/) and here: [PP-plots vs. QQ-plots](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/100383/7290).  There is also a very good overview here:  [How to interpret a QQ-plot?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/101274/)  So, what's left is primarily just understanding **[5]**, the residual-leverage plot.

To understand this, we need to understand three things:

- leverage,
- standardized residuals, and
- Cook's distance.

To understand [leverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leverage_%28statistics%29), recognize that [Ordinary Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) regression fits a line that will pass through the center of your data, $(\bar X,~\bar Y)$.  The line can be shallowly or steeply sloped, but it will pivot around that point like a [lever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lever) on a [fulcrum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fulcrum).  We can take this analogy fairly literally:  because OLS seeks to minimize the vertical distances between the data and the line*, the data points that are further out towards the extremes of $X$ will push / pull harder on the lever (i.e., the regression line); they have more *leverage*.  One result of this *could* be that the results you get are driven by a few data points; that's what this plot is intended to help you determine.

Another result of the fact that points further out on $X$ have more leverage is that they tend to be closer to the regression line (or more accurately: the regression line is fit so as to be closer to *them*) than points that are near $\bar X$.  In other words, the *residual* standard deviation can differ at different points on $X$ (even if the *error* standard deviation is constant).  To correct for this, residuals are often [standardized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentized_residuals) so that they have constant variance (assuming the underlying data generating process is homoscedastic, of course).

One way to think about whether or not the results you have were driven by a given data point is to calculate how far the predicted values for your data would move if your model were fit *without* the data point in question.  This calculated total distance is called [Cook's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%27s_distance).  Fortunately, you don't have to rerun your regression model $N$ times to find out how far the predicted values will move, Cook's D is a function of the leverage and standardized residual associated with each data point.

With these facts in mind, consider the plots associated with four different situations:

1. a dataset where everything is fine
2. a dataset with a high-leverage, but low-standardized residual point
3. a dataset with a low-leverage, but high-standardized residual point
4. a dataset with a high-leverage, high-standardized residual point

[image]
[image]

The plots on the left show the data, the center of the data $(\bar X,~\bar Y)$ with a blue dot, the underlying data generating process with a dashed gray line, the model fit with a blue line, and the special point with a red dot.  On the right are the corresponding residual-leverage plots; the special point is `21`.  The model is badly distorted primarily in the fourth case where there is a point with high leverage and a large (negative) standardized residual.  For reference, here are the values associated with the special points:

```
                              leverage std.residual   cooks.d
high leverage,  low residual 0.3814234    0.0014559 0.0000007
low leverage,  high residual 0.0476191    3.4456341 0.2968102
high leverage, high residual 0.3814234   -3.8086475 4.4722437
```

Below is the code I used to generate these plots:

```
set.seed(20)

x1 = rnorm(20, mean=20, sd=3)
y1 = 5 + .5*x1 + rnorm(20)

x2 = c(x1, 30);        y2 = c(y1, 20.8)
x3 = c(x1, 19.44);     y3 = c(y1, 20.8)
x4 = c(x1, 30);        y4 = c(y1, 10)
```

* <sub>For help understanding how OLS regression seeks to find the line that minimizes the vertical distances between the data and the line, see my answer here: [What is the difference between linear regression on y with x and x with y?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22718/what-is-the-difference-between-linear-regression-on-y-with-x-and-x-with-y/22721#22721)</sub>

Comment: Good answer that points in all the write directions for learning more.
(Gotta wonder why there's such a paucity of complete AND clear explanations of these plots)

Comment: Though [here](http://strata.uga.edu/6370/rtips/regressionPlots.html) is an example of a brief consolidated explanation for each plot.

Comment: Helpful answer, including that there are six plots available from plot.lm(). What is the red line (not dotted) in the residual plots?

Comment: @SingleMalt, the solid red line in the middle of the residuals vs. leverage plots is a LOWESS fit to the points in the scatterplot. The dotted lines are level curves.