# Interpreting linear regression residual plots using R

Tags: r, regression

I'm investigating whether there is a relationship between the day of the week and an outcome value using linear regression in `R`, and would like to understand how to interpret the residual plots.

**Data**

Example dummy data (the mean and SD are based on actual data I have):

```
set.seed(14)
mon <- data.frame(id=seq(6, 60*7, by=7), value = rnorm(60, 4372, 145))
tue <- data.frame(id=seq(7, 60*7, by=7), value = rnorm(60, 4433, 206))
wed <- data.frame(id=seq(1, 60*7, by=7), value = rnorm(60, 4671, 143))
thu <- data.frame(id=seq(2, 60*7, by=7), value = rnorm(60, 4555, 154))
fri <- data.frame(id=seq(3, 60*7, by=7), value = rnorm(60, 4268, 149))
sat <- data.frame(id=seq(4, 60*7, by=7), value = rnorm(60, 1579, 110))
sun <- data.frame(id=seq(5, 60*7, by=7), value = rnorm(60, 1136, 68))
startdate <- seq.Date(as.Date("2014-01-01"), by="day", length.out=(60*7) )
id <- seq(1, 60*7)
wd <- weekdays(startdate)
df <- data.frame(id, startdate, wd)
days <- rbind(mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun)
df <- merge(df, days)

head(df)
  id  startdate        wd    value
1  1 2014-01-01 Wednesday 4593.117
2  2 2014-01-02  Thursday 4686.159
3  3 2014-01-03    Friday 4352.982
4  4 2014-01-04  Saturday 1825.172
5  5 2014-01-05    Sunday 1206.759
6  6 2014-01-06    Monday 4276.032
```

which looks like

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=startdate, y=value, colour=wd)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth( alpha=.3, size=1, aes(fill=wd)) +
  facet_wrap(~wd)
```

[image: data plot]

**Model**

Modelling the data using `fit <- lm(data=df, value ~ wd)` produces the coefficients:

```
summary(fit)
....
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  4242.60      18.83  225.319  < 2e-16 ***
wdMonday      148.93      26.63    5.593 4.07e-08 ***
wdSaturday  -2661.93      26.63  -99.965  < 2e-16 ***
wdSunday    -3113.78      26.63 -116.933  < 2e-16 ***
wdThursday    299.65      26.63   11.253  < 2e-16 ***
wdTuesday     189.04      26.63    7.099 5.51e-12 ***
wdWednesday   412.52      26.63   15.492  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 145.9 on 413 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9896,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9894 
F-statistic:  6539 on 6 and 413 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

The plot of the data, and the coefficients seem to suggests there is a relationship between day of the week and the outcome value.

However, I know I also need to consider the residual plots when interpreting the validity of a model. For this example the residual plots are:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(fit)
```

[image: residual plots]

**Question**

Through various stats courses/uni/research (e.g. [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76226/interpreting-the-residuals-vs-fitted-values-plot-for-verifying-the-assumptions)) I know that for a good linear model you are looking for unbiased homoscedastic residuals. But my knowledge on this subject is a bit rusty. Therefore, do my residuals suggest a linear model is not an appropriate fit for the data? And/or is there another aspect to this that I should be considering, or have I completely missed the point all together?

Comment: Just an aside, linear regression will not help you assess whether or not there is a relationship between the day of the week and an outcome value.  It will, however, help you to quantify the $linear$ relationship between the two.

Comment: @StatsStudent, yes, an important distinction, thanks.

Comment: Small but telling detail: Your days of the week are ordered alphabetically "Friday" ... "Wednesday". Any order that respects order in the week will be at least a little more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your diagnostic plots I wouldn't worry about heteroscedasticity and use this model.

However, you can test if modelling the variance of residuals would improve the model:

```
library(nlme)
fit1 <- gls(value ~ wd, data=df)

fit2 <- gls(value ~ wd, data=df, weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | wd))


anova(fit1, fit2)

#     Model df      AIC      BIC    logLik   Test  L.Ratio p-value
#fit1     1  8 5332.321 5364.509 -2658.160                        
#fit2     2 14 5286.911 5343.239 -2629.456 1 vs 2 57.41009  <.0001
```

As you see, the model, which includes variance parameters, seems slightly better. However, the standard errors or t-values are only slightly different from your original model and you wouldn't infer different conclusions:

```
summary(fit2)
#Generalized least squares fit by REML
#  Model: value ~ wd 
#  Data: df 
#       AIC      BIC    logLik
#  5286.911 5343.239 -2629.455
#
#Variance function:
# Structure: Different standard deviations per stratum
# Formula: ~1 | wd 
# Parameter estimates:
#Wednesday  Thursday    Friday  Saturday    Sunday    Monday   Tuesday 
#1.0000000 1.2789517 1.2876130 0.9901914 0.5975224 1.1128592 1.5904740 
#
#Coefficients:
#                Value Std.Error    t-value p-value
#(Intercept)  4242.602  20.92298  202.77237       0
#wdMonday      148.931  27.65462    5.38538       0
#wdSaturday  -2661.925  26.39433 -100.85215       0
#wdSunday    -3113.783  23.06607 -134.99409       0
#wdThursday    299.647  29.49021   10.16091       0
#wdTuesday     189.044  33.25205    5.68520       0
#wdWednesday   412.524  26.49180   15.57175       0

anova(fit)
#Analysis of Variance Table
#
#Response: value
#           Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
#wd          6 834554455 139092409  6538.6 < 2.2e-16 ***
#Residuals 413   8785585     21273 

anova(fit2)
#Denom. DF: 413 
#            numDF  F-value p-value
#(Intercept)     1 210610.5  <.0001
#wd              6  11982.3  <.0001
```

You could model the weekdays as an ordered factor, which would cause the regression functions to use polynomial contrasts.

Comment: Thanks @Roland, Are you able to expand on the point "I wouldn't worry about heteroscedasticity", and say a bit about *why* I shouldn't worry about it?

Comment: @tospig Interpreting residual plots is something learned with experience. The variances are not so dissimilar between the groups that I would expect a strong impact on the statistics. You could do some simulations to get a better feeling for this.