# Plot Multiple Regression Output in R

Tags: r, multiple-regression

I got the results to the multiple regression, but don't know how to form a graph from it?

#Final Output with Significant Values 
summary(lm(volume~ method.C+ subject.2 + subject.6))
[image]

Comment: Can you describe what kind of graph you would like? If you type plot(yourModelName) you will get diagnostic plots

Comment: I think a question about making plots in R is off-topic here: it would be on-topic on Stack Overflow. On the other hand, a question about interpreting diagnostic plots for multiple regression would be on-topic, and there are many such questions on this site: for example http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146046/interpreting-linear-regression-residual-plots-using-r/146084#146084