# Interpreting the residuals vs. fitted values plot

Tags: r, regression

Residuals vs. Fitted Values plot

[image]

Can someone tell me which OLS assumptions might be violated according to the figure and why? Moreover, what are the consequences for the point estimators and the standard errors?

Comment: The first question is answered by http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76226/interpreting-the-residuals-vs-fitted-values-plot-for-verifying-the-assumptions

Comment: is it correct to conclude that the model is nonlinear and that there is heteroskedasticity?

Comment: Possible important violations: (i) a covariate is missing, (ii) you used a linear model for a nonlinear relationship, or (iii) the data is not independent (which is related to (i), i.e., the missing covariate could be time or spatial coordinates). If any of these apply and are as strong as in this example, other violations such as heteroskedasticity are less important.