# Why is there "residual dots" in plot() of GAM?

Tags: residuals, generalized-additive-model

After building a generalized additive model (GAM) using `mgcv` package, we can use the `plot` function to visualize the smoother, like:

```
plot(M1, resid = TRUE)
```

The `resid = TRUE` argument ensures that residuals are added to the figure.

My question is: why this plot (to show the shape of smoother) is related to **RESIDUAL**? I mean, what we are interested should be the relationship between smoother and *response variable*, not *residual*. Then why residual occur in this smoother's plot?

In my immature understanding, "**residual**" is used in plots of model validation, e.g., residuals versus fitted values, residuals versus covariates.

Comment: The residuals will show you whether the modeled relationship is right, or if there are inconsistencies.

Comment: @user2974951 But why "residuals" can show the modeled relationship, not the "observed response variable"?

Comment: Does this help https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76226/interpreting-the-residuals-vs-fitted-values-plot-for-verifying-the-assumptions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the help for the `plot.gam` function you'll see that the `residuals` argument indicates that what is added to the plots of the smooth functions are **partial** residuals, not the model residuals.

The estimated partial residual of the $i$th observation for the $j$th smooth function in the model, $\hat{\varepsilon}^{\text{partial}}_{ji}$, are given by (following Wood (2017, p.184))

$$\hat{\varepsilon}^{\text{partial}}_{ji} = \hat{f_{j}}(x_{ij}) + \hat{\varepsilon}^{\text{p}}_i ,$$

where $\hat{\varepsilon}^{\text{p}}_i$ is the estimated Pearson residual for the $i$th observation from the **full** model.

The reason we might want to add partial residuals to the partial effects plot of the smooth function is that these partial residuals should be evenly scattered about the smooth function *if* the model is well fitted to the data. They act as another diagnostic plot to assess the model fit.

#### References

Wood, S.N., 2017. Generalized Additive Models: An Introduction with R, Second Edition. CRC Press.

Comment: Nice! I misunderstanded the "residuals" used in the partial effects plot. It should be "partial residual".