# Which observation has the largest variance of the residual?

Tags: self-study, variance, least-squares, scatterplot, leverage

> a) For which of the following observations (obs1, obs2, obs3) is the variance of the residual the largest? Which observation has the highest leverage? And which one the smallest? Explain why.
>
> b) Which of the three observations has the largest DFBETAS?
>
> c) About which observation would you worry the most?
>
> [image: plot]

I thought that the answer to a) would be obs 1, because I think that will have the highest leverage because the distance from the cloud is the greatest (not quite sure whether that is true though). The rest of the questions I had no clue about. Could anyone please help?

Comment: We welcome questions like this, @aewrwaer, but we treat them differently. We try to provide hints to get you unstuck. To better understand the process, you should read the [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for the `[self-study]` tag.

Comment: You may get some initial hints from my answer here: [Interpreting plot.lm()](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/65864/7290).

Comment: @gung I have read your answer. Am I correct to conclude that since the absolute value of the $x$ of observation 1 is the largest, that observation will have the highest leverage? And that therefore the variance $(\sigma^2(1-h_{jj}))$ of that observation is the smallest? I am still not sure though in that case about questions b) and c): does a higher leverage autmatically mean a larger DFBETAS?

Comment: About leverage: try to imagine how the regression line would look like. Then remove one point at a time and draw the regression line again. Does the fitted line move a lot?

Comment: @user2378649 Hmmh, maybe it wouldn't move a lot then for observation 1, as that seems to be quite in line with the rest of the obervations. More so for 3 and especially 2. So that would then mean that observation 2 has the highest leverage, then 2, and then 1? Am I correct?

Comment: @aewrwaer, I updated my answer there to include the actual values. It may be more helpful now. Eg, high leverage does not *necessarily* mean low abs(standardized residual). In addition, although I didn't include DFBETAS, you can think of it similarly to Cook's distance; the reason the predicted values, y-hats, will change is b/c the betas change.

Comment: @gung Thank you very much for all the effort. In my case, would I be right to conclude that observation 2 has the highest leverage, then 3, then 1? Also, is it true that 2 will have the highest dfbetas?

Comment: Your `obs`'s are fairly similar to the "special points" in my other answer. Which `obs` corresponds to which "special point", & which "special point" has the highest leverage?

Comment: @gung I would say that in the terminology that you used in your answer in my case obs 1 would correspond to: 'high leverage, low  residual', obs 2 to: 'high leverage, high residual', and finally: obs 3 to 'low leverage high residual', so that then 2 also has the highest dfbetas. Am I right?

Comment: That's right, @aewrwaer. Notice that in my case, I used the same x value for both of those. In your case, it looks like x_i-bar(x) differs for your `obs`'s, so which 1 will have the highest leverage?

Comment: @gung Observation 1 has the highest leverage right? But it's not an outlier so it does not have the highest dfbetas I would say. So I think 2 has the largest DFBETAS. Is that correct? Thanks for all the help :)!

Comment: So which `obs` then, would you worry the most about & why?

Comment: @gung Observation 2 I would say? As 1 is not an outlier even though it has a high leverage. And because 2 has the highest dfbetas.