# ANOVA Theorem Explanation

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, econometrics

I am trying to figure out why the following holds:

Given $y_{i}=E[y_{i}|X_{i}]+\epsilon_{i}$ that

$E[\epsilon^{2}_{i}] =E[E[\epsilon^{2}_{i}|X_{i}]] = E[V[y_{i}|X_{i}]]$

Specifically I am trying to understand why $E[\epsilon^{2}_{i}|X_{i}] = V[y_{i}|X_{i}]$?

Clearly, I need a refresher on conditional variance and the rules for expected values....

Comment: I believe you will find the answer here, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109735/homoskedasticity-assumption-varyx-varux-constant/109748#109748, keeping in mind that $E[\epsilon\mid X]=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first equality $E[\epsilon^{2}_{i}] =E[E[\epsilon^{2}_{i}|X_{i}]]$ is just the [law of total expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_iterated_expectation).

Recall that the [variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) of $X$ is the expected squared deviance of $X$ from its expected value:
\begin{equation}
\textrm{Var}(X) = \mathbb{E}\left( \left(X - \mathbb{E}(X)\right)^2 \right).
\end{equation}
The [conditional variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_variance) is defined similarly, but now both expectations are conditional:
\begin{equation}
\textrm{Var}(X \mid Y) = \mathbb{E}\left[\left( X - \mathbb{E}(X \mid Y)\right)^2 \mid Y\right].
\end{equation}

The second equality $E[\epsilon^{2}_{i}|X_{i}] = V[y_{i}|X_{i}]$ is obtained by

1. Applying the aforementioned definition of conditional variance to $\textrm{Var}[y_i \mid X_i]$
2. Use the given part to express this in terms of  $\epsilon_i$.