# Interpreting case influence statistics (leverage, studentized residuals, and Cook's distance)

Tags: regression, diagnostic, residuals, leverage, cooks-distance

I just wanted to clarify some things about leverage, studentized residuals, and Cook's distance:

1. Does a large (in absolute value) studentized residual mean that a case is an outlier?
2. Does a large Cook's distance mean that a case is influential for sure? Similarly, does a small Cook's distance mean that a case is not influential for sure?
3. Can a case have a small leverage but a large (in absolute value) studentized residual?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No, the fact that you have a large [studentized residual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentized_residual) does not necessarily mean that the observation is an [outlier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier).  (Although some define *outlier* as simply a large residual, in which case it would be by definition.)
2. "Influential" is somewhat ambiguous.  One could think of [leverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leverage_%28statistics%29) as a measure of influence, or of DFbeta as a measure of influence, and neither of these will track Cook's distance perfectly.  Thus, [Cook's distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%27s_distance) is not necessarily the same as influence; but I imagine that you are using them as synonymous, which may be a reasonable thing to do in some context.  In that case, Cook's distance does measure influence, but that is tautological.
3. Yes, a case can have $0$ leverage (if $x_i=\bar x$), and have any size residual.

It may help you to read my answer here: [Interpreting plot.lm()](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/65864/7290).

Comment: +1  Nice answers. @K23: In respect of 1.: while some books will state that it is an outlier, at best it's an overgeneralization, since there are a number of ways to get one or more large standardized residuals that I certainly wouldn't call outliers. It may suggest *some* sort of failure of model assumptions, but I think "outlier" implies particular kinds of assumption-failure that needn't apply. There's lots of ways to get relatively large residuals.

Comment: @Glen_b, yeah, in simpler, more applied, books, large residual is often defined as outlier, & large d=influential. I see the argument for simplifying, but I don't really like it. It's like large, medium & small effect sizes, etc. I don't tend to find it that helpful to give people simple rules so that they won't have to think.

Comment: @gung: But people need some simple rules, just to get started! What I have observed as problematic is that many take this simple rules much more seriously than they were intended. As teachers we should be very careful with that.