# Calculating $R^2$ for exponential regression in R

Tags: r, regression, data-transformation, nonlinear-regression, fitting

I am fitting a simple regression model on my data and I am using `nls()`
the only problem is it does not provide the coefficient of determination $R^2$ and adjusted $R^2$.

My question is how can I calculate both of $R^2$ and adjusted $R^2$.

The data and codes are

```
# generate data

beta <- 0.012

n <- 300

Data<- data.frame(y = exp(beta * seq(n)) + rnorm(n), x = seq(n))

# plot data

plot(Data$x, Data$y)

# fit non-linear model

mod <- nls(y ~ exp(a + b * x), data = Data, start = list(a = 0, b = 0))

# add fitted curve

lines(Data$x, predict(mod, list(x = Data$x)))
```

Comment: These values aren't  reliable for nonlinear fits; see, for example, [this page](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/why-is-there-no-r-squared-for-nonlinear-regression). Their omission from `nls()` is almost certainly a feature, not a bug. If your predictor variables can be expressed in ways that `lm()` can handle, such as polynomial terms, then use `lm()`.

Comment: It never hurts to be explicit about the software you are using (here R), regardless of a tag. It can hurt to assume that everyone can work out what the software you cite is doing (not too difficult in this case, but that is not always true). If you seek specific R code to calculate descriptive measures (against some advice), then the question is off-topic on CV.

Comment: @ Nick Cox What do you mean?

Comment: Which bit don't you understand? Are you asking for code or statistical advice? See details on software-related questions at http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @NickCox Which bit don't you understand?, I think the question is clear, read the answer below, you will understand

Comment: I am not commenting on your question as such, which I understand rather well, but on your style. There is an assumption that people here all easily read and understand R code; that's just not so. This is not an R forum. I am not against R; it's just not a universal language for statistical science that everyone uses.

Comment: I just happen to use R all the time. Not all users of this site do.

Comment: @EdM That's clearly fine and consistent with my point, which is aimed at the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably end up in trouble if you try to use $R^2$ or similar characterizations of a non-linear fit produced by `nls()`. There are good reasons why there is [No R-Squared for Nonlinear Regression](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/why-is-there-no-r-squared-for-nonlinear-regression); the values for non-linear fits aren't necessarily even limited between 0 and 1. This [freely available publication](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2892436/) shows how misleading $R^2$ values can be in nonlinear fits.

Your particular example would be handled well by `lm()` with a logarithmic transformation of $y$, if there were a more typical relation of error magnitudes to scale. Typically in practice in this type of situation the error in $y$ would be proportional to its magnitude rather than, as in your example, independent of magnitude. Then you can have your nonlinear fit accomplished by `lm()`, check the quality of the fit with standard tools, and get useful values of $R^2$ and so forth if that's what you want.

Comment: thank you EdM for the answer, could you explain more please please about using lm() in this example

Comment: lm() does not work as the log(y) gives NaNs

Comment: The problem is not with R's  `lm()`: it is with what you are feeding it. Your model simulation evidently generates some negative numbers as the addition of Gaussian (normal) noise can drive the response below zero when the deterministic response is small. Given that, attempts at logarithmic transformation will inevitably fail in those cases. The combination of exponentiation and additive noise perhaps needs to be re-considered.

Comment: @Memo : If $y$ values in real data are all positive (or can be gently transformed to such a form, as with $\log(1+y)$) then `lm()` will work without complaining. Even your example data show that `lm()` can work with the log transform; ignore the NaN warnings and examine the output from `lm()` (which ignores those points), as I tried. You will find a pretty reasonable fit, although on the log scale residual error decreases with fitted values. But that is how you set up the sample data, with additive rather than proportional noise added to the underlying exponential.

Comment: @EdM and I are in almost exact agreement. I regard $\log(1 + y)$ as a gentle transformation if and only if most values are $\gg 1$. Assuming that rather than $\log y$ is however a far from trivial change to model form, however. The big issue remains that $\exp()$ guarantees postive responses, but additive noise subverts that.

Comment: Thanks Nick Cox and EdM I did lm() and it does after ignoring the NaN warning. Thanks once again

Comment: @Memo : don't forget to examine the quality of the fit produced by `lm` after transformation when you go on to real data, for example with [`plot.lm()`](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/58141/28500). The log transformation often works well, but you need to make sure it works in your case. Note that residuals were poorly behaved after log transformation and `lm()` in the example you provided. They would have been OK if you had instead written `y = exp(beta * seq(n) + rnorm(n))`, including the noise within the exponentiation.

Comment: @EdM really appreciate your help, I got the idea. Thanks