# How does outlier impact logistic regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, generalized-linear-model, residuals

I understand the outlier impact for linear regression with squared loss. @gung had [a beautiful answer in this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58141/interpreting-plot-lm) to explain the concept of leverage and residual.

My question is **How does outlier impact logistic regression**? Does the same concept apply? (that we want to have a closer look at high leverage/residual points?)

For example, `R`, `plot(glm(am~wt,mtcars,family="binomial"))` is telling me `Toyota Corona` has high leverage and residual, should I take a closer look?

[image]

---

I found [this post](https://www.quora.com/Can-Logistic-Regression-be-considered-robust-to-outliers) that says logistic regression is robust to outliers but did not discuss leverage and residual. Is it correct?

[image]

Comment: The second illustration is extremely confusing--in some instructive ways.  First, it does not exhibit any outlying responses.  We might understand the rightmost point to be a (somewhat) high-leverage one, but that's all.  Second, the fit is obviously wrong: this is a case of *complete separation.*  As such (a) there is no unique fit and (b) no matter what solution is chosen (among the correct ones), the regressor value for that rightmost point has *no influence on the solution whatsoever*!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Outliers may have the same essential impact on a logistic regression as they have in linear regression: The deletion-diagnostic model, fit by deleting the outlying observation, may have DF-betas greater than the full-model coefficient; this means that the sigmoid-slope of association may be of opposite direction. Separately, the inference may not agree in the two models, suggesting one commits a type II error, or the other commits a type I error.

This point underscores the problem of suggesting that, when outliers are encountered, they should summarily be deleted.

The implication for logistic regression data analysis is the same as well: if there is a single observation (or a small cluster of observations) which entirely drives the estimates and inference, they should be identified and discussed in the data analysis. DF-beta residual diagnostics is an effective numerical and graphical tool for either type of model which is easy to interpret by statisticians and non-statisticians alike.

There are some differences to discuss. In linear regression, it is very easy to visualize outliers using a scatter plot. The scaled vertical displacement from the line of best fit as well as the scaled horizontal distance from the centroid of predictor-scale X together determine the influence and leverage (outlier-ness) of an observation. For a logistic model, the mean-variance relationship means that the scaling factor for vertical displacement is a continuous function of the fitted sigmoid slope. Farther out in the tails, the mean is closer to either 0 or 1, leading to smaller variance so that seemingly small perturbations can have more substantial impacts on estimates and inference. However, whereas a Y value in linear regression may be arbitrarily large, the maximum fitted distance between a fitted and observed logistic value is bounded. Does that mean that a logistic regression is robust to outliers? Absolutely not.

Answer (score 0):

Logistic regression is robust to **concordant** outliers, (with an extreme X value but an outcome that accords with the X value), in a way that the linear probability model is not. See http://teaching.sociology.ul.ie:3838/logitinfl for a simple illustration.

It might be better to say that such observations are outliers for the linear probability model, but not for logistic.