# How does Outliers affect logistic regression?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, outliers

I see this is answered here :

[How does outlier impact logistic regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279010/how-does-outlier-impact-logistic-regression)

But I am not able to understand how does it affect logistic regression , can anyone take a step back and explain in a bit more simple and detailed manner.

Comment: Outliers affect logistic regression just as they do linear regression -> if you have outliers it would be prudent to deal with them.

Comment: They change the equation altogether in linear regression so how would they affect in logistic regression