# Labelled Points in plot of lm.fit

Tags: r, regression, residuals

The image shown below is the output for `plot(lm.fit)` on the Boston dataset, where `lm.fit=lm(medv~lstat)` . Why are some of the points labelled in the plot ?
[image]

Comment: This is purely a matter of reading the documentation.  The help page for `plot.lm`, which is the function that produced these plots, states "id.n: number of points to be labelled in each plot, starting with the most extreme" is the argument controlling how many points will be labeled.  By default this value is 3 (as the source code attests).  The source code also shows that "extreme" means "largest absolute residuals."

Answer (score 1):

The are considered as point of interest, e.g., outlier, high leverage, high residual points, for user to do investigation.

See this post for details on how to read the plots.

[Interpreting plot.lm()](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58141/interpreting-plot-lm)

Comment: This does not correctly describe the plots shown in the question.  From the bottom right plot it is clear that the points are not the highest leverage ones.  *Only* the points with largest absolute residuals are labeled.