# What does this graphs mean in linear regression?

Tags: r, data-visualization, regression

I don't know how to interpret these graphs. Is model well fitted? 
And how to analyze Cook's dist Vs Leverage plot? I would be very grateful for help.

[image]

[image]

Linear regresssion model shows dependence between drinks’ price=value ( given in $) and information about sunny day (1- it was sunny, 0- it wasn’t sunny).

Comment: Hello Leks, unfortunately I (we) can not help you. 1. You did not provide a graph. 2. Stackoverflow is not the right website to help you interpret regression results, there exist websites site Stackexchange for that.

Comment: I've just added the graphs. I can't find this explicit case in any other sites.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about the model you are fitting? It looks like your target variable is discrete. You may want to check https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58141/interpreting-plot-lm?rq=1