# How to detect influential points in multiple regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, outliers

I have a multiple linear regression model with two exposures and four covariates.

Can anyone please clarify my understanding on how to detect influential points?

1. Run a multiple regression model and use partial regression plots of each of the variables?
2. Look at the scatterplots of each covariate vs outcome?

Answer (score 1):

In R, there are plots to find the influential points. For example, residual vs leverage plot.

Example: `plot(lm(mpg~wt+hp,mtcars))`

Details about the plot can be found in

[Interpreting plot.lm()](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58141/interpreting-plot-lm)