# Is this linear model a good fit?

Tags: regression, linear, diagnostic

Is this simple linear regression a good fit? Are there any transformations that would improve it?

The data is discrete interval count vs discrete interval count (the count of steps walked per time)

- Variables: time spend walking ~ steps walked
- Dependent: time spend walking
- Explanatory: steps walked

**without log transform**
[image]

**with log transform on explanatory**

[image]

**with log transform on dependent**
[image]

**with log transform on dependent and explanatory**

[image]

Comment: What are your data?  What are your variables?  How many explanatory variables are there?  What are you hoping to accomplish with this model? Etc.

Comment: QQ plot shows normality assumption may be violated (a bit heavy in the tails), and Residual vs Fitted plot gives some evidence that linearity assumption may be violated. A log transformation on the explanatory may improve your linearity, and a log transformation on the dependent may improve normality. My advice is to start with the linearity as that may solve the normality.

Comment: @jros added those log transforms. It appears linearity was fixed by a log transform on both. Log transform on both does seem to fatten the tails, I am not sure of the implications of this.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58141/interpreting-plot-lm/65864#65864

Comment: You've missed out the most basic graph of all: a scatter plot of time versus steps with fitted line superimposed In this example, I'd be concerned with whether a fitted function should respect the origin 0 steps, 0 time.

Comment: This should be about the substance as well as the statistics. On the face of it time and steps should be proportional as a good first approximation. But people get tired  etc.  and so I would expect some curvature. And there is nothing here about whether your data are heterogeneous because of mixing different people and/or different conditions.

Comment: Alone the lines of what @NickCox said, this does not seem to be a place for statistical inference but rather a place for description.  The relationship can be described with a _loess_ nonparametric smoother and with quantile regression, the latter giving risk to, for example, 3 curves estimating 3 quartiles.  You might repeat the analysis using x=steps y=time per step.